# Adding new "columns" to csv data file in Tcl

Tags: csv, tcl

I am dealing with a "large" measurement data, approximately 30K key-value
pairs. The measurements have number of iterations. After each iteration a
datafile (non-csv) with 30K kay-value pairs is created. I want to somehow
creata a csv file of form:

```
Key1,value of iteration1,value of iteration2,...
Key2,value of iteration1,value of iteration2,...
Key2,value of iteration1,value of iteration2,...
...
```

Now, I was wondering about efficient way of adding each iteration mesurement
data as a columns to csv file in Tcl. So, far it seems that in either case I
will need to load whole csv file into some variable(array/list) and work on
each element by adding new measurement data. This seems somewhat inefficient.
Is there another way, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Because CSV files are fundamentally text files, you have to load all the data in and write it out again. There's no other way to expand the number of columns since the data is fundamentally row-major. The easiest way to do what you say you want (after all, 30k-pairs isn't *that* much) is to use the [csv package](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/csv.html) to do the parsing work. This code might do what you're looking for…

```
package require csv
package require struct::matrix

# Load the file into a matrix
struct::matrix data
set f [open mydata.csv]
csv::read2matrix $f data , auto
close $f

# Add your data
set newResults {}
foreach key [data get column 0] {
    lappend newResults [computeFrom $key]; # This is your bit!
}
data add column $newResults

# Write back out again
set f [open mydata.csv w]
csv::writematrix data $f
close $f
```

You would probably be better off using a database though. Both [metakit](http://www.equi4.com/metakit/) and [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html) work very well with Tcl, and handle this sort of task well.

Comment: I was onto cvs package from tcllib and experimenting with queues and an array holding all the data. This struct::matrix approach seems to be cleaner. Will give it a try! Thanks!