# Segmentation fault with Expect in TCL threads

Tags: multithreading, tcl, eval, expect

I searched a lot about this but couldn't find the answer.

I am creating multiple threads and inside them I want to use Expect's eval command to spawn scripts. But it gives segmentation fault on execution if I include Expect package inside the thread.

I am using tcltk 8.6, Expect 5.43 and threads 2.7.0

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First place to look would be to see if Expect was compiled with thread-awareness turned on. If it wasn't, all sorts of “fun” will follow.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Is there a way to check that? I am reading on so many posts that Threads and Expect don't go well together.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I know the threading issues are fixed _if Expect is built correctly_ because I can load it into a threaded Tcl build (in multiple threads at once, so no cheating) on this machine.

Comment: @DonalFellows: I will look into it. Thanks! I saw one of your answer [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773024/adding-new-columns-to-csv-data-file-in-tcl , it was very useful. Thank. I wasn't able to comment there. That is exactly what I was trying to do. But is it possible to add value in column with value separated by semicolon instead of comma, and also I want to exclude first line and add value to 10000 lines. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DonalFellows I have actually tried changing the separating character but it is not taking anything other that comma.

Comment: It's possible (of course!) but I won't answer any more than that in a comment.